# What causes an Autofield to turn off in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

Sometimes when I reopen a project, the autofields that I have set up previously are turned off. Other times they remain.

This is the Autofields Plugin. I have autofields for lengths and coordinates of some of my layers that update whenever I save that layer. By "turned off" I mean that they no longer automatically update these fields. The fields are still there, they just do not automatically update and they retain the value they last had.

What would cause autofields to toggle off? We have multiple people potentially working on a project at different times. Could that cause them to toggle off?

Comment: What do you mean by "autofield"? Are you using the AutoFields plugin, or standard fields with default values set to automatically update, or Virtual fields? What does it mean that they are "turned off"? Are the fields missing, or are they no longer updating?

Comment: My apologies, I should have been more specific. Yes, this is the Autofields Plugin. I have autofields for lengths and coordinates of some of my layers that update whenever I save that layer.  By "turned off" I mean that they no longer automatically update these fields. The fields are still there, they just do not automatically update and they retain the value they last had.

Comment: Of the multiple people sharing the project, are they all working on the same computer? If not, do they all have the AutoFields plugin installed? Are they all using the same version of QGIS?

Comment: Different computers, just checked with my coworker and he is using 2.18.22 and I am using 2.18.28. Would that be the issue? We both have the Autofields plugin

Comment: I don't know if the difference between 2.18.28 and 2.18.22 would matter. You could check if both of you have the most recent version of the plugin. Also, who was the last to use the project when it turns off the autofields? If it was the older version of QGIS they could try updating to 2.18.28. If that doesn't fix it, I can't troubleshoot any further because I haven't used this plugin. I use QGIS 3, which has two different built-in features to auto-update fields.